# Getting AWS web instance in private subnet to send data to new relic

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi I am a noob here in server fault. I would like to know is it possible for a server instance in AWS private subnet, with no public IP but have a NAT, to actually run a new relic daemon to pass server data to new relic so that it can display on the website. Cos so far I tried, and I managed to SSH into the instance via IP table redirect from NAT server but every time I do a "sudo yum update" all the libraries download get time out. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

It's likely you just need to add a default route to your VPC configuration, pointing to the ENI of your NAT instance.

The other option is to associate an EIP with your private instance. You don't need to create any inbound Security Group rules, but a side effect of assigning an EIP is that AWS will then handle any egress traffic for you, with their NAT infrastructure.

Comment: if this is a private subnet, adding an EIP will not help, you would need an Internet gateway as well (and it would not be a private subnet anymore). +1 for the NAT however, NewRelic uses "push" and just need an internet access.

If your NAT is not working, also check that:
 - you have a route from your private subnet to the NAT instance's ENI 
 - your NAT accepts traffic from your private instance (check security group inbound)
 - you deactivated the source/dest check on your NAT instance (right click your instance and deactivate this check)